# Unable to connect to remote oracle database using odbc driver

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odbc

I am unable to connect to a remote oracle database using the instantclient_21_12 odbc driver.

I am attempting to connect to an oracle database remotely using an odbc connection. I am running instantclient_21_12.

I believe the odbc credentials I am using are good because when I test the connection in the odbc setup I get the following message:

[test success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHXlf.png)

The program I am running is built in c# and I've edited an example I found on oracle's website:

```
string MyConString = "Dsn=TEST;uid=username1;pwd=password1";

//Connect to MySQL using Connector/ODBC
OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
MyConnection.Open();

Console.WriteLine("!!! success, connected successfully !!!");
```

I do not get to the success log. I originally got the first two errors:

ERROR #0
Message: [Oracle][ODBC]Optional feature not implemented.
Native: 0
Source: SQORA32.DLL
SQL: HYC00

ERROR #1
Message: [Oracle][ODBC]MTS support not available, could not load ORAMTS.DLL
Native: 0
Source: SQORA32.DLL
SQL: HY000

Then by looking in the odbc configuration, I disabled this one "Disable Microsoft Transaction Server" box and now all I get is the second error:

[odbc config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL0CG.png)

ERROR #0
Message: [Oracle][ODBC]MTS support not available, could not load ORAMTS.DLL
Native: 0
Source: SQORA32.DLL
SQL: HY000

I think there are more odbc configuration options I could try. Or alternative application methods I could try, but I haven't been able to find much success googling. Any suggestions?